# ASP.NET MySql connecter error

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm working in a little project and I uploaded to that host: [Somme](https://somee.com/Default.aspx)
I'm using MySql database and to work on ASP.NET I added the connecter to the main folder here is a image of the files I added and where:

[image]

So on localhost this runs fine, but when I'm running on the host I get this error:

[image: Error]

Someone can help me? I already sherch for the problem and can't find a solution, sorry for my english.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does it work in localhost?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers yes, works without any problmes

Comment: I think you need to upload dlls also from solution folder. I did same before 1 year. So I don't remember exact solution. But I remember, I uploaded dlls

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers ok thanks let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have those files available on the server you have to set the `Copy To Output Directory` to Copy always or Copy when newer.

You can do this by right clicking the dll's and going to properties. You'll have that option in there.